# Question about iteration and optimization

Tags: python-3.x, loops, nested

New to Python 3 and I decided my first project would be a web scraper...

I'm looking to iterate once and grab all the values I need the first time over. Is there an easier way to do this rather than the way I've done it?

I've tried doing it as one loop with the three nested loops inside and only the first values would end up in the array.

```
        for card in soup.find_all("div", class_="result"):
            for card in card.find_all('a', attrs={'class': 'jobtitle'}):
                job_data['Job Title'] = card.getText().strip()

        for card in soup.find_all("div", class_="result"):
            for card in card.find_all('span', attrs={'class': 'company'}):
                job_data['Company'] = card.getText().strip()

        for card in soup.find_all("div", class_="result"):      
            for card in card.find_all('div', attrs={'class': 'summary'}):
                job_data['Summary'] = card.getText().strip()

            print(job_data)
```

I'm just really wondering if there's a neater way of doing this -- my current code works but it doesn't seem like the most elegant solution...

Answer (score 0):

As your initial loop is the same, you can do all three of your inner loops in one run of the outer loop. You also probably only want to print the data once, so make sure not to indent that line.

This can be seen in the following:

```
for card in soup.find_all("div", class_="result"):
    for card in card.find_all('a', attrs={'class': 'jobtitle'}):
        job_data['Job Title'] = card.getText().strip()
    for card in card.find_all('span', attrs={'class': 'company'}):
        job_data['Company'] = card.getText().strip()
    for card in card.find_all('div', attrs={'class': 'summary'}):
        job_data['Summary'] = card.getText().strip()

print(job_data)
```